# Is it possible to call a REST API on vuetify datatable on data loading, searching, paging and sorting?

Tags: javascript, rest, api, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the datatable from vuetify

I am wondering whether on [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEbqNM) there is something that can be done to call a REST api to perform the different operations instead of having everything in-memory when the table is loading data, paging, searching or sorting data?

The `html`:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Nutrition
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          append-icon="search"
          label="Search"
          single-line
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :search="search"
      >
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-results>
          <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
            Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
          </v-alert>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The `javascript`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: i understood that you want to get only the data of the first page when you load the table and when you go to the second one you will request its data from the api?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim exactly!

Comment: you could custom your api by paginating its data items and using `update:pagination` event to load only the data of the given page

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim mind giving an example? Tbh, I am still relatively new to vue.js.

Comment: could you give more details about your api?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, pagination.sync is what you are looking for

Basically, there are three key parts:

1) Add a pagination obj to data and a watcher:

```
watch: {
    pagination: {
        handler() {
            this.fetchDesserts();
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

and in data:

```
pagination: {
    rowsPerPage: 100,
    descending: false,
    sortBy: "name",
    page: 1
  },
```

2) Preload your desserts from memory or api:

```
mounted() {
    this.fetchDessert();
}
```

3) update your datatable props to include pagination.sync, total-items and display pagination:

```
 :headers="headers"
 :items="desserts"
 :pagination.sync="pagination"
 :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems"
 :total-items="totalItems"
```

Here is an update codepen, that shows the general idea and includes the use of search: 
https://codepen.io/retrograde/pen/pmzQNP?editors=1010